# How to echo hex from python

Tags: python

I get `TypeError: must be string without null bytes, not str` when I run this code. I want to echo the hexadecimal code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

test = '\x76\x06\x40\x00'
cmd = "echo '"+test+"'"
os.system(cmd)
```

I have tried various echo flags like -e along with r in python but it just ends up echoing `\x76\x06\x40\x00` and not the actual characters.

The code works fine if I change the `\x00` (null) to something like `\x0A`

Comment: What are you expecting to be printed for the null terminator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the module binascii ( 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html )

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import binascii
test = '\x76\x06\x40\x00'
print( "%s\n" % binascii.hexlify(test)  )
```

Version with shell call

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import binascii
import os
test = '\x76\x06\x40\x00'
print( "from python:%s\n" % binascii.hexlify(test)  )
cmd = "echo 'from shell:"+("%s\n" % binascii.hexlify(test))+"'"
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: I want to echo from the shell because ultimately I am going to pipe it into a command

Answer (score 1):

why do you need to echo? You can print from your python program and | another command

```
$ cat x.py
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

print '0x10'
print '0x20'

$ ./x.py  | wc -l
   2
```

Or maybe I am not getting the question?